# jQueryUI datepicker redisplays after selection

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, durandal

The datepicker is managed by knockout-jqueryui in a Durandal view presented as a modal dialog. The calendar pops up when the corresponding INPUT is focussed, and hides when it is blurred. Data-binding works fine.

But when the user selects a value, the calendar closes, the INPUT updates **and the calendar re-displays**. It works, but it's annoying my users because they are mouse obsessed and the calendar obscures the control below, making it hard to click on it. Yes, I know they could press tab. I have pointed this out.

How can I stop the re-display? Ideally, triggers for display would be focus and keydown. I have no problem with configuring it to manual control and switching with `data-bind="change: showCalendar, ..."` or similar, if that's how one does this.

So, what's the usual way to go about this? If it's manual control as I describe above, what are some keywords to expedite finding the relevant section(s) in the documentation? (How to set it to manual and how to hide/show it manually.)

(I found show() and hide())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The showOn option for jQuery UI Datepicker is passed through by knockout-jqueryui.

It defines only two values, 'focus' and 'button'.

There is no explicitly defined mechanism to disable auto-display, but I found that a value other than the defined values has the desired effect. I am passing 'click'.

Manual control methods are show and hide.